# expected begin_array but was begin_object at line 1 column 2 path $ object

Tags: android, array, get, retrofit

me esta saltando el error especificado en el titulo

**"expected begin_array but was begin_object at line 1 column 2 path $"**

¿cómo puedo llamar a un objeto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cómo verán mi respuesta es

***{
"CODIGO": 13,
"RAZON_SOCIAL": "CANON MEDICAL SYSTEMS"
}***

Pongo mi código, quizás hay algo que no estoy viendo y desde otras perspectiva me ayudaría mucho.

mi objeto

```
public class _03011aDatareq {

    @SerializedName("CODIGO")
    @Expose
    private Integer codigo;
    @SerializedName("RAZON_SOCIAL")
    @Expose
    private String razonSocial;

    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Integer codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getRazonSocial() {
        return razonSocial;
    }

    public void setRazonSocial(String razonSocial) {
        this.razonSocial = razonSocial;
    }
}
```

mi interface (Imagino que acá iria " Call <_03011aDatareq> ge....." ) no? si es asi lo que me traba es plasmarlo en mi MainActivity para ponerlo en un textView

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

    @GET("jderest/v3/orchestrator/03_011B_ORCH")
    Call <List<_03011aDatareq>> getDatareqs(@Query("CUIT")String cuit,
                                        @Header("Authorization")String authHeader,
                                        @Header("Cookie") String cookie,
                                        @Header ("Content-Type") String content);
}
```

y mi mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textViewResult;
    private TextView textoCodigo;

    _03011aDatareq datareq1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_Resul);
        textoCodigo =findViewById(R.id.textPrueba);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://qcsys.servehttp.com:922/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

        JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);

        String userName ="xxxxx";
        String password ="xxxxx";
        String base = userName + ":" + password;

        String authHeader = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(base.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

        Call <List<_03011aDatareq>> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getDatareqs("30716002361", authHeader,"JSESSIONID=fYAV2KfouyICoHiKGuJ5n_-Q0kQOc-KNl6HmFk9Ce8K5JQtuMa7A!-530853743", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

        call.enqueue(new Callback <List<_03011aDatareq>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<_03011aDatareq>> call, Response<List<_03011aDatareq>> response) {
                if(response.body() != null) {
                    textoCodigo.setText("code: "+ response.code());
                    return;
                }

                List<_03011aDatareq> posts = response.body();
                for (_03011aDatareq post : posts) {
                    String content = "";
                    content += "ID: " + post.getCodigo() + "\n";
                    content += "Text: " + post.getRazonSocial() + "\n\n";
                    textViewResult.append(content);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<_03011aDatareq>> call, Throwable t) {
                textoCodigo.setText(t.getMessage());

         }
     });
   }
}
```

he tenido respuesta de **código 200**, que tengo entendido que es una conexión exitosa.

desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: El json es un objeto pero en tu método de api Call <List<_03011aDatareq>> getDatareqs están diciendo que te devuelva una lista, entonces pon Call<_03011aDatareq>, debería funcionar.

Comment: sisi lo sospechaba y lo probé, gracias!

te hago una consulta, cómo podria plasmarlo en mi textview al json en mi llamada de metodo ?

Comment: Mira el siguiente enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63316186/retrofit-android-display-data-in-textview

Answer (score 1):

Si el error indica:

> "expected begin_array but was begin_object at line 1 column 2 path $"

en idioma español:

> "Se esperaba begin_array pero era begin_object en la línea 1, columna
> 2, ruta $"

indica que se esperaba un array pero estas obteniendo un objeto, de hecho la respuesta es exitosa como comentas pero puedes ver que estas obteniendo un objeto como respuesta:

```
{ "CODIGO": 13, "RAZON_SOCIAL": "CANON MEDICAL SYSTEMS" }
```

Debes modificar para poder procesar un objeto (`Call<_03011aDatareq>`) no un array (`Call <List<_03011aDatareq>>`):

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

        @GET("jderest/v3/orchestrator/03_011B_ORCH")
        Call<_03011aDatareq> getDatareqs(@Query("CUIT")String cuit,                                   @Header("Authorization")String authHeader,
                                            @Header("Cookie") String cookie,
                                            @Header ("Content-Type") String content);
    }
```

Comment: Sisi justo estuve averiguando en otros posts y lo que me comentas es totalmente cierto, me funciona, ahora estoy teniendo problemas en querer plasmar el objeto respuesta en un textview. tendrias algun modelo o ejmplo que pueda seguir, es lo unico que me falta, te lo re agradeceria